# Flip animation when controller pushed on iPhone

Tags: iphone, animation, rotation, push, flip

I had a look around and didn't find what I was exactly looking for.

Is there a way to get a flip animation when pushing a view controller?

I read that you can change the animation by using a modal view controller but AFAIK the animation for a modal view is from bottom to top and that's not what i am looking for. Is there a way to get a flip animation somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For modally presented view controllers, you can change the animation with the `modalTransitionStyle` property. AFAIK, there is no way to change a navigation controller's push animation (except rebuilding UINavigationController from scratch).

Comment: Okay, should be enough for now ;) Thks.

Comment: After a long hunt i got this **github** link. It is working for me https://github.com/devindoty/iOS-Transition-Pack

Answer (score 50):

something like this should work

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animation" context:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: yourviewcontroller animated:NO]; 
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO]; 
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

don't forget to set animated to NO when calling pushViewController

Comment: can we slow down the animation l'll bit?
Its quite fast..
Regards

Comment: you can use setAnimationDuration to specify a duration in seconds  
like
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];

Comment: 0.7 seems to be about right, if you want it to match the Weather app.

Comment: Yes, the `animated:NO` is important.  Thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 15):

This also works.. for `iOS 4.0 and greater`

```
[UIView  transitionWithView:self.navigationController.view duration:0.8  options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                             animations:^(void) {
                                 BOOL oldState = [UIView areAnimationsEnabled];
                                 [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
                                 [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
                                 [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:oldState];
                             }
                             completion:nil];
```

Comment: I doesn’t work well in iOS7, as the view animation is cut in half and then “jumps” into position when animation is done. The discouraged Apple way still works perfectly though.

Answer (score 4):

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animation2" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.7];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO]; 
[UIView commitAnimations]; }
```

in the new viewcontroller will make it flip back the same way (instead of sliding left) when the back button in the toolbar is pushed -- make sure animation is enabled here, e.g., if you make a custom button to pop the stack, use:

```
- (void) backToPrevious: (id) sender 
{
    //[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: As mentioned in the [UIView docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html), the `beginAnimations:context:` method is part of a group of methods Apple are discouraging developers from using (from iOS 4 and on). They recommend using UIView's block-based animation methods instead (for example, `animateWithDuration:animations:completion:`).