# navigationController setup pop transition style

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

Is it possible to change popToViewController transition style for UINavigationController? I need the same style as for pushViewController method?(I mean from right to left style(pushViewController), not left to right(popToViewController by default)).

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480458/change-animation-transition

Comment: thanks, but it only changes for transition animation. I need the same style transition for pop as push style.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the Push and Pop animations in a navigation based app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215672/how-to-change-the-push-and-pop-animations-in-a-navigation-based-app)

Answer (score 1):

For modally presented view controllers, you can change the animation with the modalTransitionStyle property. AFAIK, there is no way to change a navigation controller's push animation (except rebuilding UINavigationController from scratch).
https://github.com/devindoty/iOS-Transition-Pack

OR

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animation" context:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: yourviewcontroller animated:NO]; 
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO]; 
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506647/iphone-flip-animation-when-controller-pushed

Comment: whether this answer is useful for you to solve your problem?If so please accept or rate my answer